# Add an enter to string every 22 characters, waiting until a space

Tags: python, enter

I am trying to get my code to insert a `\n` into my code every 22 characters, but if the 22nd character is not a space it waits till there is one then inserts the `\n` there.

I have tried looking up some code for the past hour on StackOverflow, but most seem to break with some changes, because they where specifically made for that problem.

Here is some code I have tried

```
count = 0
s = "I learned to recognise the through and primitive duality of man; I saw that, of the two natures that contended in the field of my consciousness, even if I could rightly be said to be either, it was only because I was radically both"
newS = ""
enterASAP = False
while True:
    count += 1
    if enterASAP == True and s[count-1] == " ":
        newS = (s[:count] + "\n" + s[count:])
    if count % 22 == 0:
        if s[count-1] == " ":
            newS = (s[:count] + "\n" + s[count:])
        else:
            enterASAP = True
    if count == len(s):
        print(newS)
        print("Done")
        break
```

I am wanting it to produce a text like 
`I learned to recognise
 the thorough and primitive` 
.......

Note that it waits for the space and then the count resets at from `the` to `primitive` rather than adding on the 5 extra letters that the code waited for the space.

The code that I have produces the exact string it starts with. Which baffles me

Comment: I would suggest to look at builtin module `textwrap`

Comment: Set  ```enterASAP``` to False after     ```if enterASAP == True and s[count-1] == " ":
        newS = (s[:count] + "\n" + s[count:])```

Comment: Wow, the textwrap module does exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot Andrej, if you or someone else can put this in answers I will accept it and close this

Comment: each time you assign  newS = (s[:count] + "\n" + s[count:]) , it will override the previous one. So finally when you print newS you will get only one newline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the version with `textwrap` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/textwrap.html)):

```
import textwrap

s = "I learned to recognise the through and primitive duality of man; I saw that, of the two natures that contended in the field of my consciousness, even if I could rightly be said to be either, it was only because I was radically both"

print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(s, 22)))
```

Prints:

```
I learned to recognise
the through and
primitive duality of
man; I saw that, of
the two natures that
contended in the field
of my consciousness,
even if I could
rightly be said to be
either, it was only
because I was
radically both
```